# Find an element with a specific data attribute jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I understand that I can always iterate down the DOM tree and check every element for a data field and if the value is correct but I would like a cleaner solution.  For example

```
    <div id="theDiv">
       <div>
         <span data-num="3" ></span>
         OTHER HTML
       </div>
       <div>
         <div><span data-num="23"></span><div>
         OTHER HTML
       </div>
       <div>
         <span data-num="3"></span>
         OTHER HTML
       </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a jQuery one liner to find all spans with data-num=3?  I know I can find all spans by

```
  $("#theDiv").find(span).each(function(e) { ... });
```

but I would like something like

```
  $("#theDiv").find(span > data-num=3).each(function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: Yes there is, but i forgot the exact syntax, but I am sure someone will have it for you. Or you can look up the css to find selector via attribute value

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use the [**Attribute Equals Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
 $("#theDiv span[data-num='3']")
```

[**Try it!**](http://jsfiddle.net/FfjZ9/)

Comment: Darn, I was just about to write that. +1 anyway.

Comment: The selector here is nor correct. It is looking for the data attribute on the element with the id, not the span!

Comment: Thanks.  Upvotes all around.  Works perfect (i was toying with the old example and it wasn't working but I now know why :)).  Is there any way I can use the same syntax to find spans with data-num=ANYTHING?  as not all spans have a data-num

Comment: @user974896 just leave out the `='3'` part

Answer (score 1):

only for example ( filter)

```
$('#theDiv span').filter(function(){ return $(this).data("num") == 3});
```

Comment: Did not want to itterate through all the spans and wanted a simple one liner.