# Hide data-id on load and Show On Click of A Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onload, quicksand

I currently have an image gallery with a filtering capability which is in Wordpress. Each image in the gallery possesses a  `data-id` (eg `data-id="id-148"`).

I'd like to ask help on how to code on `jQuery`. I hope to have a multiple set of `data-ids` to be removed (or hidden) when the website loads then when I click on certain buttons (a `href`) with specific Class, these `data-ids` will then be showed.

Let's say `onLoad` the images with `data ids: 148, 149, 150` will be hidden then `onClick` of a button with a particular class `class="Apples"` then `148` will show. If I click button with `class="Orange"` then `data-id 149` will show. When I click `class="All"` the `data-ids`mentioned above will be hidden again.

The image is located in a list-item as such:

```
<li class="one-third column" data-id="id-148" data-type="Apples">
```

Hope to have some help. Thank you so much.

Comment: what do you mean "the data ids; 148, 149, 150 will be hidden"? they're not shown, they're just some data stored in some elements!

Comment: Post some actual code please, does each `data-id` have a `data-attribute`

Comment: Hi Amin. Thanks for pointing out my error in explanation. I have images possessing those data-ids. Let's say 'Image 1 has a data-id of 148' then 'Image 2 has a data-id of 149'. When the website loads those images possessing the mentioned data-ids will be hidden.

Comment: Sorry guys. I had an error with the button. The buttons do not have a data-attribute but a css Class.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you get some enlightenment from this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("some_button").click(function(){
     // Get data-* value using data();
     var dataAttribute = $(this).data("attribute");
       if(dataAttribute == "Apples")
         $("li[data-id='148']").show();
   });
});
```

References:

[Find an element with a specific data attribute jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747750/find-an-element-with-a-specific-data-attribute-jquery)

Comment: Hi Kyle. Thank you. I just had an error with the button as I checked back in the site. The button does not have a data-attribute but only a css Class..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click','.mybutton', function(){
     var att = $(this).class();
     $("li[data-type ="+att+"]").hide();
   });
});
```

This is untested but will match the data-type against the data-attribute

Edit: Changed to take class from button

Comment: Thanks Donald. I had an error with he button. The button does not have a data-attribute but only a css Class.. I apologize and thanks again.

Comment: @Niccolo the edit now takes the class from the button and places it into `att`

Comment: Thanks again Donald. But the code doesn't work.. Is it possible that the specific data-ids (148, 149, 150) are hidden when the page loads? Then it shows when clicking my button with class of "Apples" then hides back when I click a button with a Class of "All". Thank you thank you.