# Change element on web with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner web developer.

I have script:

```
function updateBaskket(productId, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/update-basket',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            productId: productId,
            quantity: quantity
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.basket-summary-amount').html(data.summary + ',- zł');
            $('[data-item-price=productId]').val(123);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

    $('.quantity').on('change', function () {
        if($(this).attr("data-id") != undefined && $(this).val() != undefined){
            updateBaskket($(this).attr("data-id"), $(this).val());
        }
    });
```

It's work fine. In result I have:

```
{"productId":"2","price":"1.35","totalProductPrice":"23.12","summary":"16604.67"}
```

The key is productId

I need to find at the moment on the site:

1. data-item-price="2" => 5291.35 and change value from 5291.35 to 1.35 (price)
2. data-item-totalprice="2" => 15874.05,- zł  to  23.12 (totalProductPrice)

On the website I have different items (with different id) data-id / data-item-price / data-item-totalprice. I would only like to update those that have id = 2

How can I make it?

Please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an element with a specific data attribute jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747750/find-an-element-with-a-specific-data-attribute-jquery)

Comment: can you show me, how can I use it?

Comment: Please read the documentation, try things out. You won't learn if someone just spoon-feeds you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('[data-id="'+data.productId+'"]').data({ 'item-price': data.price, 'item-totalprice': data.totalProductPrice });
```

Comment: elements that are changed in different places of the page

Comment: @trifesk you'll need to provide a [mcve] so that we can provide a more extended answer.  "It's not working" is different from "it doesn't do 100% exactly what I need" (which is what you appear to be saying).